# Can't change the CSS on my Wordpress Header

Tags: css, wordpress, adobe

I have a Wordpress.com website. I want to change my header text to an Adobe font. I copied the following CSS from the Adobe website:

```
font-family: viktorie, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
```

I formatted it as:

```
h1 {
font-family: viktorie, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

I am using the Bold Grid Customizer and the Hifidel Theme on the Wordpress.com website. I put that code into the BoldGrid CSS customizer and none of the text changes (and I also got an error message for 'sans-serif' so I removed it).

I tried the code this way (to see if anything would happen) and it worked on the paragraph text:

```
p {
font-family: viktorie,
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

but I only want to change the header text, not the paragraph text. I need to know what I'm doing wrong, how to correctly format the CSS (if it's incorrect), and if I'm placing it in the wrong area. I've been working on this for two days, tried three different chat rooms, googled... and I cannot find an answer to this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: with chrome - right click the heading - inspect, look at all the styles on your h1, and if it has a child element inside the h1, and look at the computed value. edit the value in chrome to see if it works

Comment: If you are trying to override as a pose to replacing, you will need to use !important